# Java exposing configuration elements to program

Tags: java, config

First off, let me state that I really wasn't sure if this was a SO question or a Programmers SE question, I started here, because this community is far more active.

I have a config file stored in a java properties file:

```
java_config=something
java_another=something else
```

I have an enum which controls the building of this config:

```
public enum ConfigFactory {
    INSTANCE;
    
    private Map<String, String> mSettings = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
    public void build(String path) {
        // load config file into mSettings, 
        // where the property k/v are stored in the hashmap as a k/v
    }
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is what the "best" way to expose the k/v to the system is.  Is the solution as simple as:

1. Using the `java_confg` and `java_another` throughout the program, or
2. Create a `final String` var that indirectly references (not reflection) `java_config`?

## Solution #1:

```
/**
 * addendum to ConfigFactory
 */
public String getValue(String s) {
    // return value from key
}
/** end of addendum to ConfigFactory **/

/**
 * Invoked somewhere in the program
 */
ConfigFactory.Instance.getValue("java_config");
```

But using the above method would require a ton of changes if the config's keys ever changed.  Which is exactly what I want to avoid.  But it is super quick, ConfigFactory will have a "smaller" heap-memory footprint (actual gain depends on number of strings declared), and it is obvious to which value I am actually referencing in `ConfigFactory`.

## Solution #2:

```
/**
 * addendum to ConfigFactory
 */
 public static final String JAVA_CONFIG = "java_config";
 public static final String JAVA_ANOTHER = "java_another";

 public String getValue(String s) {
     // return value based on key from mSettings
 }
 /** end of addendum to ConfigFactory **/


 /**
  * Invoked somewhere in the program
  */
  // use of indirect reference to the "java_config" string literal
  ConfigFactory.INSTANCE.getValue(ConfigFactory.JAVA_CONFIG);
```

This keeps the config attributes contained within the ConfigFactory exclusively and removes the dependency on the literal string name (*Solution 1*), but now ConfigFactory must be littered with many `public static final String` declarations, which makes the heap-memory footprint larger, and it isn't explicitly clear what key I'm actually referencing.

I understand the pros and cons of each method.  I'm unsure if:

1. There is a better solution than the two listed,
2. *Solution 2* truly a "better" solution than *Solution 1*, or
3. A singleton pattern for configuration is the best approach

While this question directly references `properties`, this is a question that would also apply to any configuration file used to establish a baseline for Java programs.

Comment: Don't post on a site because it's active. Post where it's on-topic. That said, A vs B questions seldom do very well on Code Review. Why not just put the code you're using up for a peer review and see what you get?

Comment: I think most reviewers would rule out solution 1 pretty quickly: "java_config" is just another kind of magic number.

Comment: This question is right where it belongs. The author has one problem and two potential solutions (neither of which have been fully implemented yet, and so they cannot possibly be ready for code review).

Comment: "ConfigFactory must be littered with many `public static final String` declarations, which makes the heap-memory footprint larger, and it isn't explicitly clear what key I'm actually referencing..." There are a few things wrong about this statement: (1) It's not "litter"; it's information, (2) the memory footprint is probably inconsequential, and regardless it's the same as solution 1 anyhow because of the way Java manages String literals, and (3) your variable names should have good names, maybe even clearer names than the String literals.

Comment: @DavidS, Uh, yes we do. Code needs to work in order for it to be on-topic on Code Review. Incomplete/un-implemented code is broken, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: I will implement the code with `solution 2` and submit to codereview.  `Solution 2` is the way I am leaning towards.  Thanks for the comments and the input.

Comment: I'd recommend enum over String constants. It's basically exactly what enum was designed to handle: a fixed set of constants. It's also what's conventionally used in the standard library, such as [Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html).

Comment: @DavidS, won't that get untenable if the number of defined properties gets quite large?

Comment: @lilott8, That's a good question, and you should consider maintainability when thinking about pros and cons. What would happen if you needed to add, remove, or change a configuration parameter for each of these solutions? (In these cases, enums actually have significant benefits over String literals or constants, but I must leave it to you to learn more.)

Comment: I added this to codereview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105300/jave-exposing-configuration-elements-to-program

@DavidS I think I figured out your solution using enums.  If it is what I think it is, I really like it.  Could you please post it on the codereview post? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get ample help over there, @lilott8, including someone to explain the enum improvement. I'm going to go eat lunch, but I've upvoted your question.

Comment: @DavidS As a moderator on Code Review, it's my duty to recommend you to read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). Additionally, I'd like to invite you to our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if you want to further discuss the scope of Code Review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP couldn't discern where this post belonged and neither could the commenters.  Closing it is sufficient as the OP moved his question to CodeReview himself.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @SimonForsberg. I've read that now, but it hasn't really changed my viewpoint. "Insufficient context" is a subjective call. Personally, I think the user provided sufficient context in _this question_ for a useful review, and having read lilott's new question on codereview, I feel the same way: the new question has added a few more lines of explicit code, but it has the same amount of useful context. Fortunately the system is self-regulating, so if I'm in the minority here, little harm will come from it.